# ReactJS - Audio Distortion in AudioContext Playback During Frequent Component Re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, audiocontext

I am encountering an issue with audio playback in a ReactJS application, specifically with the audio being choppy or distorted. The problem appears to coincide with the addition of a new function that updates the display of the current time. I am working with the AudioContext API to handle audio playback and I am facing these audio distortion issues while updating the current time display every 100 milliseconds.

Here's the function in question:

```
const startDisplayingCurrentTime = () => {
  clearInterval(interval.current);
  interval.current = setInterval(() => {
    setCurrentTime(audioContext.current.currentTime - pausedDuration.current);
  }, 100);
};
```

This function is intended to update a progress bar displaying the current time of the audio track. The progress bar is a child component that receives the current time as a prop:

```
<ProgressBar
  currentTime={currentTime}
  duration={totalDurationOfSourceNodes}
  progressBarClickToNavigate={progressBarClickToNavigate}
/>
```

The function startDisplayingCurrentTime clears an existing interval (if any), and then sets a new interval that updates the currentTime state every 100 milliseconds. The updated currentTime state is then passed down to the ProgressBar component.

I noticed that the audio playback becomes choppy whenever this interval is active. When I comment out the startDisplayingCurrentTime function and the corresponding ProgressBar component, the choppiness seems to disappear and the audio plays normally.

It seems like the frequent re-rendering of the UI, triggered by the setCurrentTime function, might be causing this issue. I'm looking for a way to maintain the same functionality - updating the current time display every 100ms - without the accompanying audio distortion.